# how to compare between points of different number of dimensions?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, multidimensional-array, pca, svd

I have a data points of different dimensions and I want to compare between them such that I can remove redundant points. I tried to make the points of the same dimensions by using PCA, but the problem is that PCA reduced the dimensions, but I lost what each dimension mean as the resultant points are different from the points that I had, so I wonder if there is any other way to do so. In other words, I wonder if there is any way to help me compare between points of different number of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Assume relevant null values for missing dimensions? For instance if you want to compare a 2d (x,y) point (vector) with a 3d one (x,y,z) you can assume a z-value of 0 for the 2d point. That corresponds to the x,y plane.